# How to remove 3 decimal places if it is a whole number in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Example:
(data type: `DECIMAL(10,3)`)

```
8.000
9.067
89.650
```

And I want this:

```
8
9.067
89.650
```

I think it is a case statement but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What is the data type of the data you're having? `DECIMAL`? `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Decimal and I use this (10,3)  format.

Comment: Would you expand on what you're trying to do please. Are you trying to store data as integers in a column that expects `DECIMAL`? Are you trying to change it to an integer *after* querying it from the DB?

Comment: Thanks Patrick for collaboration, I mean, I'll try to change it to an integer after querying it from the database.

Comment: `8.000` and `8` are mathematically the same, and so are `89.650` and `89.65`. It is usually better to do the formatting right when you display the values to your users. Are you using some kind of application to fetch the values from the database, such as a PHP, C++, or Java program?

Comment: And now this is, it I'll try Trim (`Quantity`) +0 and my problem were solved. I dont know whyTRUNCATE cannot resolve this Ex: TRUNCATE (8.000,3) it well return also 8.000 at my MYSQL version 5.7.11

Comment: By the way thank you guys for helping me. God bless you all.